# Launcher and panel disappeared after enabling Wobbly Windows and Desktop Cube effects

Tags: 11.04, compiz, panel, fullscreen, ccsm

I updated to Ubuntu 11.04, and simultaneously enabled the Wobbly Windows effect and the Desktop Cube effect in `ccsm`. After I restarted Ubuntu, the panel and launcher disappeared and the screen went into fullscreen mode. I am unable to open any files; I can only see a desktop screen.

Answer (score 4):

Compiz is known not to work too well with cube in natty. Get to the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run command

```
unity --reset
```

and then go back to wall setting in compiz.

And if you will not be able to get to terminal then right click on desktop and create launcher for it - command line is

```
gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve it by starting compiz in the terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) with `ccsm` command, then go to the "Desktop" category and check on "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". It will say that there is a conflict and you should resolve it, press mostly on the left button :).