# Unity 3D stops working after changing Compiz settings

Tags: unity, 11.10, ccsm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

After I upgraded my Ubuntu 11.04 (that I had Compiz) to 11.10 and did some navigation in CompizConfig Settings Manager, suddenly the main top panel and left launcher disappeared and I just have windows menu at the top instead of master panel (master panel = top panel that have shut down , time and date , chat  and ...).

But it still working in Ubuntu 2D.

How can I reset my Unity and why did this happen?

Comment: I had the same problem and could resolve it. See my answer in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/45216/launcher-and-panel-disappeared-after-enabling-wobbly-windows-and-desktop-cube-ef/73135#73135